# Passing information to ashx page and determinate which image will appear in asp-image-control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, handler

How can I pass an information to a handler page? And how can I specify which image will be displayed in the asp-image-control?

Handler1.ashx.cs code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
             int id1 = something //how can I pass a information to a handler page
             int id2 = somthing 2 // same case

                byte[] IMG = classP.RedImg(id1);
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(IMG);

                byte[] IMG2 = classP.RedImg(id2);
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(IMG2);
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Page.aspx code:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
```

Page.aspx.cs code behind:

```
string[] data = classC.ReadClient();
int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]); //Here is id1 value
int id2 = Convert.ToInt32(data[1]); //Here is id2 value

Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?ID=" + id1.ToString();
Image2.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?ID=" + id2.ToString();
```

thanks :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. The handler will be called once per request. So returning both images like that will not work.
2. In `ProcessRequest`, you need `context.Request.QueryString["ID"]` to get the ID query string parameter that you're adding in the codebehind.

You'll have to call `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` on that value, since `RedImg` appears to expect an int. The best course of action there would be to first get the value from the query string, check that with `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, and bail out early if it is. Then use `int.TryParse` on the value, and then also bail out of that returns false. You should probably also set `context.Response.StatusCode` to 404 or something along those lines to make it more "proper" HTTP.